# Git patch create and send it to an email

Tags: git, git-send-email

I just created a patch using the following command `git format-patch master --stdout > raj_powar.patch`

In order to send the '**raj_powar.patch**', i ran the following command `git send-email --subject="stringval"  --to="address" raj_powar.patch`

But i keep getting the error "**No subject line in raj_powar.patch ? at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email** "

What am i doing wrong, how do i email this patch?

Answer (score 0):

Your format-patch command didn't specify a range of commits, so likely your patch file is empty.  If you just want a patch for the top commit on master, you can use "-1" or use "master^..master".

Use `git format-patch -1 master --stdout > raj_powar.patch` instead.

Comment: So @Michael to follow, if i wanted the range of commits on master  would it be **git format-patch master^..master --stdout > raj_powar.patch**. This is first the time i am using git format-patch

Comment: Hi Raj, master^ refers to "the commit before master".  What range do you want?  The format is `start:end`.  (the "start" commit is not included)